# Turn off scroll event after lazyload content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm trying to figure out how to unbind from the scroll event once all the images have loaded. This is the best I've got so far, but really I want to actually unbind it, like by using [$.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and/or [$.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) somehow. I'd rather not create the vars `totalNumImages` and `alreadyLoaded` for comparison if there's a better way. I could call [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) within [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) if that would make it more possible. Ideas?

```
var $images = $('img.lazyload')
  , alreadyLoaded = []
  , totalNumImages = $images.length
;//var

$(window).on('scroll.myNamespace', function() {
    $.each($images, function(i) {
    if ( !alreadyLoaded[i] && inViewport(this) ) {
        $(this).attr('src', savedImgSrc); // Load image.
            alreadyLoaded[i] = true;
    }
    });
});//on
```

Comment: Rather than comparing the count, another idea I had was to do `$(this).addClass('alreadyLazyLoaded')` inside the loop and do `$images.not('.alreadyLazyLoaded')` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

On and off are to delegate events, not to bind events; so should be using:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ /* the code */ })
```

And where you want to unbind just use:

```
$(window).unbind('scroll')
```

Comment: Thx-yea can compare `alreadyLoaded.length` to `totalNumImages`. That's no problem. The issue is how to turn off the handler. Using `$.off()` *inside* `$.on()` doesn't seem work. If `$.off()` is *outside* `$.on()` (like I believe its intended usage is) then there needs to be a way to trigger calling it after hitting `allLoaded` as opposed to after when the code is parsed.

Comment: No, you shouldn't compare alreadyLoaded.length to totalNumImages because arrays in javascript are filled to its maximum key; for example if you write: var arr = [], and then arr[34] = true; then the array length would be 34, not 1. 

But your problem is using on and off; that is not how thos were meant to be used, you shoul use the function scroll and then just use unbind.

Comment: Good call about the array length. This gets around that:  `alreadyLoaded.join('').length === totalNumImages` see http://jsfiddle.net/v9teB/2/ According to the `$.bind()` docs "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document." Here either can be used. But the real trick is making a custom event handler tthat triggers when all are loaded. See the solution I posted.

Comment: Yeah, but that trick only work when you are dealing with booleans and one digit numbers. BTW, you already fixed the code so .off() works now and you should close the question: http://jsfiddle.net/v9teB/4/

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a custom event handler that [triggers](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) when all the images are loaded. This works like a charm:

```
var $images = $('img.lazyload')
  , $window = $(window)
  , alreadyLoaded = []
  , totalNumImages = $images.length // stays the same
;//var

function doLazyLoad() {

    $.each($images, function(i) { 
        if ( alreadyLoaded[i] ) { 
            return; // Quit asap if already loaded.
        } 
        if ( inViewport(this) ) {  // inViewport and loadImage
            loadImage(this);       // are defined elsewhere.
            alreadyLoaded[i] = 1;  // Add item to array.
        }
    });

    // Trigger custom event when all have been loaded:
    if ( alreadyLoaded.join('').length === totalNumImages ) {
        $images.trigger('customEventAllLoaded.myNamespace');
    }

}//doLazyLoad

// Attach doLazyLoad() to the scroll event:
$window.on('scroll.myNamespace', doLazyLoad);

// When the custom event is triggered, run a one-time event
// handler that detaches doLazyLoad() from the scroll event.
$images.one('customEventAllLoaded.myNamespace', function() {
    $window.off('scroll.myNamespace', doLazyLoad);
});
```

The docs recommend using on/off rather than bind/unbind. Both ways would work for this. The [$.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method only runs once.